# Excel VBA code to find max cell value in column and delete all rows below it

Tags: vba, excel

I have hundreds of .csv files (with data in columns A and B) to clean up and I think a macro would be useful to process this data quickly.

The goal of the code is to locate the cell with the maximum value in Column A and delete all of the rows below it

So far, my code is

```
Sub DeleteRowAfterRange()

    Dim maxValue As Long
    Set maxValue = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(Columns("A"))

    With Sheets("Sheet1")
        .Rows(maxValue & ":" & UsedRange.Rows.Count).Delete
    End With

 End Sub
```

I run the macro in the VB editor and see Compile Error: Object Required while this portion of code is highlighted

```
maxValue =
```

in the line

```
Set maxValue = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(Columns("A"))
```

I have searched through various forums and found questions that are similar to mine, but I am not familiar enough with the syntax to figure out what the issue is in my code. I would greatly appreciate any assistance and am looking to learn how to correctly revise this code

Comment: unless your `maxValue` = the row in which it is found your Delete will delete the wrong rows.

Comment: what do you mean?
e.g for the following data in column A: 1,3,4,5,6,8,3,2,3,2,1
the code should locate the cell where "8" is and delete all of the rows below them ("3,2,3,2,1")

Comment: nope, the Max function returns the value not the row in which it is found.  so it will delete all rows after and including row 8

Comment: You are getting the error because you are trying to set the variable as a range, but the max returns a number, not a range.  If you delete the `set` you will notice that it will work, but will only return the max number, no information about where that is found as Scott Craner said.

Comment: is there any reason that you do not delete the rows before the "max" row?

Answer (score 2):

You do not `Set` a Long, it is not an object.

The Max function does not return the location but the actual number.

We can use Match on the number to return the row.

```
Sub DeleteRowAfterRange()

Dim maxValue As Long

With Sheets("Sheet1")
    maxValue  = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(.Range("A:A")), .Range("A:A"), 0)
    .Rows(maxValue  & ":" & .UsedRange.Rows.Count).Delete
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Scott. I tried running your code, but now I see Compile Error: argument not optional

Comment: On which line??

Comment: my apologies for the late response.
The error is in this line:
    maxValue  = 
  
  Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(Application.WorksheetFunction.M
    ax(.Range("A:A")), .Range("A:A"), 0)

Comment: I am not getting any error, but it looks like you have a space in the word `Max`

Comment: Sorry, I just typed it wrong. There is no space. I'm not sure why I'm still getting an error, would this code work on excel 2010 and newer?